# ActiveReport Customization

Tags: c#, activereports

I am working on Customization using ActiveReport3, i have a exception which is raised for the following code. Can anyone help...? Please provide me with the contents of ActiveReport3.
    Here is the code...

```
public void grpHBillInformation_Format()
{
    slno=0;

                     if(((DataDynamics.ActiveReports.TextBox)rpt.Sections["grpHBillInformation"].Controls["txtModeofPayment1"]).Text =="1")
                     {
                            ((DataDynamics.ActiveReports.TextBox)rpt.Sections["grpHBillInformation"].Controls["txtModeofPayment1"]).Text = "Cash";
                     }
                     else
                     {
                            ((DataDynamics.ActiveReports.TextBox)rpt.Sections["grpHBillInformation"].Controls["txtModeofPayment1"]).Text = "Credit";
                     } 
                    if(((DataDynamics.ActiveReports.TextBox)rpt.Sections["grpHBillInformation"].Controls["txtCustomerfName1"]).Text!=" ")
                     {
                            **((DataDynamics.ActiveReports.TextBox)rpt.Sections["grpBHillInformation"].Controls["txtCustomerName1"]).Alignment=TextAlignment.Center;**
                     }

}
```

Here alignment of the text i need to make it as center if at all there is no customer 1st name.

Comment: Please post the exception as well.

Answer (score 0):

Please post the exception.  just looking at the code, it seems that you need to give the fully qualified name of "TextAlignment.Center"

Comment: This should be a comment